# Small World, what does "permanently discard" mean?

Tags: small-world

In Small World, after conquering region for loosing player rules state:

> Permanently discard one Race token back into the Storage tray

Now I'm not totally sure what does that mean. For most races there really is no difference, but for skeletons and sorcerers I see two interpretations that lead to two different results:

> Move tokens back to the box/tray from where you took them, this means that skeletons and sorcerers can use them again, that is their maximum token count is not affected

OR:

> Move tokens back to the box, and not to the tray where you took them from. Meaning that maximum possible count for skeletons and sorcerers would be decreased this way.

While I understand that tray is place where you take tokens from, the word "permanently" is a bit confusing. I have been playing by second interpretation so far, and it seems kinda fairer. Though I'm not sure if this is the intended way to play game. Though difference would most likely be minor, only two races are affected, and the number of tokens is quite large and hard to deplete. Still theres a difference! So anyone knows what how this should be handled officially?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it says "back into the Storage tray", it is the first option; Skeletons and Sorcerers can reuse them. Note the limitation in the rules for both Skeletons and Sorcerers:

> If there are no more tokens **in the storage tray**...

Both Skeletons and Sorcerers state that the new unit comes "from the storage tray", and the rules for the loosing player state that the killed unit goes "to the storage tray".